# Can sp_MSforeachDB be used for DBCC CheckDB without errors being masked?

Tags: sql-server, dbcc-checkdb

I have a test database with an index I intentionally corrupted to test `DBCC CheckDB`.

When I run:  `DBCC CHECKDB (Test2) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS, DATA_PURITY`

I get, as expected:

```
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 2105058535, index ID 2, partition ID 72057594038845440, alloc unit ID 72057594039762944 (type In-row data): Page (1:156) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 2105058535, index ID 2, partition ID 72057594038845440, alloc unit ID 72057594039762944 (type In-row data), page (1:156). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -4.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 2105058535, index ID 2, partition ID 72057594038845440, alloc unit ID 72057594039762944 (type In-row data). Index node page (0:0), slot 0 refers to child page (1:156) and previous child (0:0), but they were not encountered.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 3 consistency errors in table 'Names' (object ID 2105058535).
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 3 consistency errors in database 'Test2'.
repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (Test2).
```

However, when I run:  `exec sp_MSforeachDB 'DBCC CHECKDB (?) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS, DATA_PURITY'`

I get no errors.

I understand that sp_MSforeachDB is not supported.  However, several blogs suggested using sp_MSforeachDB to check all the DB's on a SQL Server Instance.

Question:  Am I doing something wrong, and if so, what is the fix, or is this some idiosyncrasy with `sp_MSforeachDB`?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like `sp_MSforeachDB` is skipping your Test2 database. This is one of many known issues with `sp_MSforeachDB` as noted by Aaron Bertrand:

- [Execute a Command in the Context of Each Database in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/)

You can confirm by removing the `NO_INFOMSGS` parameter:

```
exec sp_MSforeachDB 'DBCC CHECKDB (?) WITH DATA_PURITY'
```

This should cause messages to be returned for every database. Search the results for your Test2 database. I bet it isn't there.

With `DBCC CHECKDB` all error messages are displayed by default. Specifying or omitting the `WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS` parameter has no effect.

You may like to look at Ola Hallengren's solutions for [SQL Server Backup, Integrity Check, and Index and Statistics Maintenance](https://ola.hallengren.com/).

Comment: Please mark as answered if my answer helped you.  Thanks!